# Call a JS function only when <1000 px on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been dealing with that for a few hours and I can't find a solution.

I need to call a function just when screen size with is < 1000px (iPad vertical orientation), and comment/deactivate the function when screen size is > 1000px (iPad landscape orientation).

I wrote the following code, It works well, but when I rotate the iPad (from vertical to landscape) the function does not being commented as expected.

It's been a quite complicated to explain. Hope you can understand my problem.

```
$(window).ready(function(){
if ( $(window).width() > 1000) {
/*  $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).doubleTapToGo(); */
}
else {
$( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).doubleTapToGo();
}
});

$(window).resize(function(){
if ( $(window).width() > 1000) {
/*  $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).doubleTapToGo(); */
}
else {
$( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).doubleTapToGo();
}
});
```

Have a nice day, bye!

Comment: you code working for me http://jsfiddle.net/a6mfwnyr/4/ see console

Comment: What is in the doubleTapToGo() function? It looks to me like you should be be using bind() and unbind() http://api.jquery.com/bind/ to bind your function or remove it. As it stands you are calling doubleTapToGo() every time your rotating and could be binding the same event multiple times. I would personally like to see more code.Also you can't "comment out" a function after you've called it elsewhere. That comment is just that,a comment.It has no effect on the code. You need to unbind->bind everytime you add the function(so exists once only) and just unbind when you don't want it

Comment: TommyBs. Thanks for your reply. What a great explanation!.

I'm using this code: http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly

I have no idea about bind/unbind, I will look forward for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to *disable* DoubleTapToGo if width > 1000px?

Did you use [this code](http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly)? Then I don't think that's possible. You can only enable it.

--edit--

Okay, I've added a minor change to the doubletaptogo.js file. You can [find it here](https://github.com/boogerschmidt/fiddles/blob/master/doubletaptogo/doubletaptogo.js).

Now to reach the desired effect, do this:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ( $(window).width() > 1000) {
    $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).data("doubletaptogo-enabled", false);
  }
  else {
    $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).data("doubletaptogo-enabled", true);
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' )
    .data("doubletaptogo-enabled", ($(window).width() <= 1000))
    .doubleTapToGo();
});
```

Haven't tested it yet but it should work.

Comment: Okay! Then you'd have to modify that code a bit. I can look at it and will edit my answer if I find something.

Comment: Thanks dude, I would appreciate a lot!

Comment: THANKS THANKS!. Oh man you can't believe how much I'm happy now!. I've tried on an iPad and it works like a charm!

PS: You forget the ); on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.matchMedia`, and then use media-queries to target the current orientation:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)") {
    // ...
}
```

Further info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

Inside the code snippet you supplied:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)") {
        /*  $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).doubleTapToGo(); */
    }
    else {
        $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).doubleTapToGo();
    }
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)") {
        /*  $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).doubleTapToGo(); */
    }
    else {
        $( '.head_bar_nav ul:has(li)' ).doubleTapToGo();
    }
});
```

You can also use the media-queries to target the `device-width` but if you want to target orientation, it's better to use the `orientation` expression.

There's also this nice blog post by David Walsh about identifying orientation change:
http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change

Comment: I've tried the code on an iPad and does not work. :(.